# Two aircraft with same air speed, blank angle, but different mass, are the radius of turn the same?

Tags: aircraft-physics

Two aircraft with same airspeed, blank angle, but different mass, are the radius of turn the same?

Comment: What have you done to try and answer this homework question by yourself? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are the aircraft the same type? Same wing configuration?  Are they flying at the same altitude and speed?